# Hosting a RESTful API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, hosting, api-design

I'm a C# ASP.NET junior dev and have worked with Code First C# Databases, RESTful API's, MVC & Vue (a frontend framework sort of like React) to create websites.

Now at work and during my education, I've never handled deployment.

At this time I have a personal project. I have succesfully hosted my relational MySQL Database on phpMyAdmin and can update it from my local desktop.
My hosting site let me know they do not host C# or anything of the sort.

I found some posts suggesting Azure, AWS, others, but for every post I find I find equal people protesting those.

What is a good site to host my first REST API? I'm looking for something that can go beyond Minimum Viable Product and I'd like to host my website under the hosting service I'm currently using (so not paired hosting with the API).

What would the costprice look like for an API that's deployed and being used by clients?

I realize this cost depends on the amount of traffic, but assume a basic API used for, let's say, posting orders in an online shop (though website/app/w.e, it all would communicate through the API).

Any tips are welcome as I feel I'm swimming in the dark researching this.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is a bit too broad/opinionated for a concise answer, so it will likely be closed soon. Anyway, the answer mostly depends in which direction you want to go for your learning experience path. Nowadays, everything 'runs in the cloud', so you may go with Azure/AWS,..., but that may cost you some $$$. On the other hand, you may want to deploy something to your own machine instead, so get a grip of VM, Docker, Kubernetes, or any other service orchestration solutions first. These concepts can be later ported to other platforms too.

Comment: From the offerings I know, probably the easiest most straight forward way of getting a REST API up and running (to play around with, _not for live systems_) is with Azure Functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition.

Answer (score 0):

Any hosting service that grants you *real* access to a machine will be able to run your API as some specialized for the .net/core ecossystem.

I supposed you know about php based on phpMyAdmin service and the ecossystem of hosts that support php, although cheaper they do not exactly give you access to the machine and probably will not support .net/core as inumerous others tech stacks.

As a Junior Developer I believe you should have a little bit of practice in any deployment ecossystem so I encorage you to try most of the big clouds (Azure, GCP, AWS), but also some smaller hosts to gain experience and understand a bit more about the differences in deployment and ecosystem.

Azure will be really easy, you can create an account and post your API without any costs using an free WebApp, VS will even have publishing tools that will handle 90% of the job, GCP will be a little trickier and will require you to know a bit about containers and clusters, if you go for a non specilized host like digitalocean you will need to understand more about the Operational system and associated servers/controllers to deploy and publish

about the cost part is a lot more difficult. It will depend on the host that you are using and the load (process, memory, size, and throughput of data). In my experience I had some very small-scale APIs that required more processing or memory to accomplish some tasks like PDF generation than a medium-scale API that only had json data transaction